# Display one line of two with sed

Tags: shell, sed, line, display

I'm trying to understand a shell command : `sed -n 'p;n'`

with this you will be able to print on line of two, I'm trying to understand  how it command works (`n;p`), why is it having this behaviour.

For example if I'm doing `p;n;n`, it will select one line of three, but `p;p;n` it will print twice the first line, hide the second one, print twice the third one etc., why it isn't printing the first and second line, and hide the third one ?

I hope I was a bit clear, it's hard to explain my problem, if anyone can help me.

Comment: [Number 66 in this list](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-two/) (the second version) is very similar.

Comment: Don't do any of this cryptic, unintuitive, convoluted, non-scalable, unmaintainable nonsense, just use awk instead for anything other than s/old/new/ on individual lines. The awk equivalent to that sed command is `awk '(NR%2)==1'`, i.e. it prints every other line. Want to print every 7th line? `awk '(NR%7)==1'`. Want to print every 3rd line containing "foo"? `awk '/foo/ && (++cnt%3)==1'`. And so on. All clear, obvious, and consistent. sed is great for s/old/new but for anything else, just use awk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**`sed -n 'p;n'`**

`-n`  suppresses all output that isn't explicitly printed.

`'p;n'` is the sed script to run on each input line. The semicolon is a separator between two commands, `p` and `n`.

`p` **prints** the current line, without moving to the next line.

`n` moves to the **next** line without printing anything.

Once these two commands have been run on the current line, sed moves on to the next line, and then runs the script again on this new line. This script will keep running until there are no more input lines. The effect of the script is to keep printing, then skipping lines.

---

**`p;n;n`**

This is mostly the same script, but it skips two lines instead of one.

---

**`p;p;n`**

This is mostly the same script, but it prints the line twice before skipping it.

---

> why it isn't printing the first and second line, and hide the third one ?

Because `p` doesn't advance sed forward a line, only `n` (or reaching the end of the script) does that.

(It might be helpful to note that `sed -n 'p'` prints every line without skipping any, `sed -n 'p;p;p'` prints every line three times, and  `sed -n 'p;n;p'` is equivalent to `sed -n 'p'`.)

Answer (score 0):

Ollin's answer is enough to explain. I only want to add how to hide third line.

To skip every third line:

```
sed -n 'p;n;p;n'
```